# How to let wordpress automatically add a featured image?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to let wordpress automatically add a featured image at new posts.

**Conditions:**

- The post category id must be 3
- Each author/user has his/her own image.
- The images (already uploaded) have the following name format:
  [firstname author]-[lastname author].jpg.

For example; when Steve Jobs submits a post, the submitted post category id should be 3 and the featured image set for this post should be 'steve-jobs.jpg'.

FINAL WORKING CODE:

```
function set_featured_image_blog_post() {
    global $post;
    $already_has_thumb = has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID );
    $post_category = get_the_category( $post->ID );
    if ( !$already_has_thumb && $post_category[0]->cat_ID  == 3 )  {
        if( $post->post_author == 3 ){
            set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 165 );
        }
        else if( $post->post_author == 4 ){
            set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 166 );
        }       
    }
}

add_action('the_post', 'set_featured_image_blog_post');
add_action('save_post', 'set_featured_image_blog_post');
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'set_featured_image_blog_post');
add_action('new_to_publish', 'set_featured_image_blog_post');
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'set_featured_image_blog_post');
add_action('future_to_publish', 'set_featured_image_blog_post');
```

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail

Comment: How do I know the thumbnail_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**final code:**

```
function set_featured_image_blog_post() {
    global $post;
    $already_has_thumb = has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID );
    $post_category = get_the_category( $post->ID );
    if ( !$already_has_thumb && $post_category[0]->cat_ID  == 3 )  {
        if( $post->post_author == 3 ){
            set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 165 );
        }
        else if( $post->post_author == 4 ){
            set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 166 );
        }       
    }
}

add_action('the_post', 'set_featured_image_blog_post');
add_action('save_post', 'set_featured_image_blog_post');
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'set_featured_image_blog_post');
add_action('new_to_publish', 'set_featured_image_blog_post');
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'set_featured_image_blog_post');
add_action('future_to_publish', 'set_featured_image_blog_post');
```